How to create Pagination in flutter using API
i am new in flutter recently i am working on a project i face to problem that i can not solve it please answer to my question my question is: i have list of products which is store in api, i fetch products from api but it has two filed in header one page and other is per_page. i want to create a pagination with my product list the pagination concept already set in api it means i have two filed page means which page i want to display and per_page how many records i want to show in one page. i simply retrieve the first page with 7 record : https://fms-dev.asrepoya.com/api/products?per_page=7&page=1  but i want to retrieve all pages with 7 records , it should create a pagination for every page for example page first 7 record, page second 7 records..... until end of records , i should click on fist page and only show me 7 records, if i click on page second 7 different records. this is my api fetch product :
 Future<List<Product>> getProductList({token}) async {
final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('$path/products?per_page=7&page=1'),
    headers: header(token: token));
// print('Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
// print('Response body: ${response.body}');
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
  List<dynamic> productList = jsonResponse['data']['data'];
  List<Product> products =
      productList.map((item) => Product.fromJson(item)).toList();
  return products;
} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to load product list');
}

}e here

You can use infinite_scroll_pagination
if you want example that work with state management check this
Flutter How to make paging at Future<void>
create you paging your PagingController
final pagingController = PagingController<int, productList>(firstPageKey: 1);

add this to your initState
 pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
      handleGetProductList(page: pageKey); 
    });

Future
Future<void> handleGetProductList({required int page}) async {
    try {
      final res = await getProductList(page: page, perPage: 10); // change per page here
      if (res.length < perPage) {
        pagingController.appendLastPage(res); // if your fetch data less than perPage mean it was last page after this it will not fetch more page
      } else {
        pagingController.appendPage(res, ++page);
      }
    } catch (err) {
     pagingController.error = err;
    }
  }

Your API
Future<List<Product>> getProductList({required String token , required int page , required int perPage}) async {
final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('$path/products?per_page=$perPage&page=$page'),
    headers: header(token: token));
// print('Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
// print('Response body: ${response.body}');
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
  List<dynamic> productList = jsonResponse['data']['data'];
  List<Product> products =
      productList.map((item) => Product.fromJson(item)).toList();
  return products;
} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to load product list');
}

Widget
infinite_scroll_pagination has different widget you can choose you can read thier docs for more info in this example will be PagedListView
PagedListView(
   pagingController: pagingController,
   builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<productList>(
   itemBuilder: (context, item, index) {
           return Container(
             child : Text(item.memeName)
               ); // Your Widget
            },
          ),
      )

